# PC doesn't boot after adding RAM

Tags: windows-10, boot, memory, motherboard, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have Lenovo M91P 7052-b5u i5-2400 ([spec sheet](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/pdf/system_data/m91p_tower_tech_specs.pdf)) with 2+1 GB RAM

[image: look like this].

Because I have 4 sockets, I decided to add 2 more.

Yesterday I added Kingston 4+2 GB RAM  99u5471, but the PC didn't boot. It was black screen - no POST.

I thought maybe the new RAM wasn't compatible - but after I took out the old 2+1 RAM, everything worked just fine.

So right now the PC boot only if I putting OR only the old RAM OR only the new RAM but not both of them.

What can cause this?
Is it because the size is different? (the Kingston is smaller than the old ones)

(I already tried to switch between the sockets)

Thanks!

Comment: My best guess is a difference in speed between different types of RAM chips.  Getting the same make/model for all chips may fix this.  (Yes, that might mean replacing some working equipment in order to get some more-compatible equipment.)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the BIOS battery before adding new RAM modules, then check the new RAMs one by one to see which works. When you are dealing with RAMs, sometimes PCs won’t boot, because it needs a BIOS reset, even if the RAM modules are working well. Also, different types of memory modules don’t work together in some cases – they must be the same make and model to work correctly.

Comment: Tried.. didn't work... Why different types are causing trouble..?

Comment: Even if specs are same but because they are from different manufacturers that may cause compatibility problems... Some different RAMs works together, some not. I think that's the case

Comment: there is nothing to do ha..? Out of curiosity - does the size says something about the performance?

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine registered and unbuffered RAM on the same motherboard at the same time. Your existing RAM was registered, the RAM you added was unbuffered.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ram is required to be upgraded in pairs with the same size and spec. Use the Crucial Ram Scanner which will tell you what ram you need and if it needs to be upgraded in pairs or not

http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner

Comment: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Lenovo/thinkcentre-m91p - can't see nothing about it...